# Filter table with multiple dropdowns with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have been trying to use multiple dropdowns to filter my table with the `hide()` and `show()` functions in jQuery and not just filter if the table contains a string, but if it equals to a certain string.

Image: [image]

Until now I was able to just use 2 dropdowns and make them able to filter the first two columns. I don't know how I can make it work properly with all 8. Maybe I am just thinking a bit to complicated.

I want all dropdowns to work properly and filter the table.

```html
<div class='grid-container'>
  <div id='first' class='grid-item'>
    <label class='font-header'>Hersteller:</label>
    <select class='fstdropdown-select' id='first'>
      <option value=''>Auswählen</option>
      <option value=". ++$a .">".$row['Hersteller']."</option> .
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id='second' class='grid-item'>
    <label class='font-header'>Artikel:</label>
    <select class='fstdropdown-select' id='second'>
      <option value=''>Auswählen</option>";
      <option value=". ++$a .">".$row['Artikel']."</option> .
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
//this is the first dropdown menu seen on the picture
$("#first").change(function() {
  // .rows is the class of the tr 's
  $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').show();
  var end = this.value;
  var firstDropVal = $('#first .fstselected').text();

  if (firstDropVal == "Auswählen") {
    $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').show();
    firstDropVal = $('#second .fstselected').text();
    if (firstDropVal == "Auswählen") {
      $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').show();
    } else {
      $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').hide();
    }
  } else {
    $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').hide();
    firstDropVal = $('#second .fstselected').text();
    if (firstDropVal == "Auswählen") {
      firstDropVal = $('#first .fstselected').text();
      $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').hide();
    } else {
      $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').hide();
    }
  };
});

//this is the second dropdown menu seen on the picture
$("#second").change(function() {
  $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').show();
  var end = this.value;
  var firstDropVal = $('#second .fstselected').text();
  if (firstDropVal == "Auswählen") {
    $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').show();
    firstDropVal = $('#first .fstselected').text();
    if (firstDropVal == "Auswählen") {
      $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').show();
    } else {
      $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').hide();
    }
  } else {
    $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').hide();
    firstDropVal = $('#first .fstselected').text();
    if (firstDropVal == "Auswählen") {
      firstDropVal = $('#second .fstselected').text();
      $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').hide();
    } else {
      $('.rows:not(:contains(' + firstDropVal + '))').hide();
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: use a class for select, then instead of ID use class for change event, and add name to selects, so on change you have name of the column and selected value, by one function only

Comment: The logic needs to be completely re-thought.  Rather than try to hide / show for each dropdown, instead create a function that checks each row against ALL conditions, and hide / show the row accordingly.  The code as-is will be an absolute nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @cale_b My problem is that each condition is changeable in realtime so i dont really know how i can create one function that checks each row against all conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Make you filter with one class and add name element relevant to your column

here **mitarbeitertable-filter** as filter class

```
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
   <select class="form-control bottomborder mitarbeitertable-filter input-small" name="k_kollegetyp">
       <option value="">Bitte Auswählen</option>
       <option value="1">Festangestellter</option>
       <option value="2">Freie Mitarbeiter</option>
       <option value="3">Kunde</option>
       <option value="4">Lizenzbenutzer</option>
     </select>
 </td>
 <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
      <select class="form-control bottomborder mitarbeitertable-filter input-small" name="id_unit">
       <option value="">Bitte Auswählen</option>
       <option value="1">Consulting GmbH</option>                                                             
       <option value="2">Communication GmbH</option>                                                                                                                            
       <option value="3">Promotion GmbH</option>                                                                                                                                              
       <option value="5">Sales GmbH</option>                                                                                                                            
       <option value="6">AG</option>                                                                                         
  </select>
</td>
```

in JS , and if you are using ajax based the you will receive it as filter column in your post

```
$('.mitarbeitertable-filter').on('keyup change input', function (e) {
  var searchArray = {};                
  $('.mitarbeitertable-filter:visible').each(function( index ) 
   { 
       var name = $(this).attr('name');
        searchArray[name] = $(this).val();
   }
  $("#table").dataTable().fnMultiFilter(searchArray) 
})
```

PS:fix it according to your needs

Comment: This answer is unworkable, based on OP's request.  You're using DataTables, and nothing about the question suggests that is a part of the question.